# How to include multiple input methods and render the output in DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am creating and implementing a survey using Shiny. One of the questions is a typical matrix/battery question with the two bottom rows being two different ways of answering the question. The first is a row of check boxes allowing respondents to select more than one column, and one row of radio buttons that only allows them to select one.

I have been able to create a matrix question using only one row of radio-buttons or multiple rows of radio buttons. I have also been able to run [this](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/93) example using text and check box input, but whenever I include the radio buttons everything seems to stop working.

Below is a minimal example to give an idea of what I want to do. I have omitted the submit button, but included the output of `y1` and `y2` to show that there appears to be a disconnect when a button is selected.

```r
# UI
ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("X1"),
                verbatimTextOutput("y1"),
                verbatimTextOutput("y2"))

# Server
server <- function (input, output) {
  # Set up matrix
  X <- matrix(runif(10), nrow = 2)

  # Create the HTML for radio buttons
  radio_buttons <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(X), ncol = 1)
  checkbox_buttons <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(X), ncol = 1)
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(X))) {
    radio_buttons[i, ] <- sprintf('<input type = "radio" name = "%s" value = "%s"/>',
                                  paste0("y1"), i)
    checkbox_buttons[i, ] <- sprintf('<input type = "checkbox" name = "%s" value = "%s"/>',
                                    paste0("y2"), i)
  }

  # Add to X
  X <- cbind(X, checkbox_buttons, radio_buttons)

  # Render the table
  output$X1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    t(X), server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', options = list(
      dom = "t", paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
    )
  )

  output$y1 <- renderPrint({input$y1})
  output$y2 <- renderPrint({input$y2})
}

# App
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The table renders fine, but it appears that the input values are not registering.

Any ideas for solutions would be much appreciated.

NB! The real table is larger and the number of columns is dynamically created. I will also implement a maximum of three boxes checked down the line.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use HTML code embeded in a DataTable? What is the DataTable doing for you? If you are just using the table to create the layout of your form then you should know that went out of style in the 90's. Mostly we use `div`, `box`, `row`, and `column` in Shiny. Maybe a list of easy to use Shiny based inputs can help you. https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html

Comment: You can actually use `renderUI()` to create Shiny UI elements dynamically. Then you can use all the easy and pretty shiny UI elements dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues**

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. The checkbox elements need an `id` attribute to be referenced.
2. The radiobuttons need a parent element with an `id` and  `class = "shiny-input-radiogroup"` (`tr` is a suitable element for that) -> this we need to add via JavaScript in the callback function.
3. You wanted to anme your inputs `y1` and `y2` but this was already the name of your outputs.

---

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("X1"),
                verbatimTextOutput("y1"),
                verbatimTextOutput("y2"))

# Server
server <- function (input, output) {
  # Set up matrix
  X <- matrix(runif(10), nrow = 2)

  # Create the HTML for radio buttons
  radio_buttons <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(X), ncol = 1)
  checkbox_buttons <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(X), ncol = 1)
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(X))) {
    radio_buttons[i, ] <- sprintf('<input type = "radio" name = "%s" value = "%s" %s/>',
                                  paste0("rb_1"), i, ifelse(i==1, 'checked = "checked"', ""))
    checkbox_buttons[i, ] <- sprintf('<input type = "checkbox" value = "%s" id = "%s" />',
                                     i, paste0("cb_", i))
  }

  # Add to X
  X <- cbind(X, checkbox_buttons, radio_buttons)

  # Render the table
  output$X1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    t(X), server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', options = list(
      dom = "t", paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
      drawCallback = JS('function() {
                           var $radio_row = $(\'tr:has(input[name="rb_1"])\');
                           var $row = this.api().table().rows($radio_row);
                           var $this = $($row.nodes(0));
                           $this.attr("id", "rb_1");
                           $this.addClass("shiny-input-radiogroup");
                           Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());
                           Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());
                         }')
    )
  )

  output$y1 <- renderPrint({list(input$cb_1, input$cb_2)})
  output$y2 <- renderPrint(input$rb_1)
}

# App
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This appears to do exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the clear explanation of why the code did not work.